# How to set the price to my own new asset?

Tags: stellar-core

Good day
I have created the my own new asset in stellar public network.
I'd like to set the price to my asset. for example, it should be 50 USD.
How to set the price to my asset?
OR other methods?

Any tips thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to set a fixed price on an asset. You have to make an account and sell and buy the asset from that account by making buy/sell orders. If you want to sell the asset for XLM, you'll have to set up a bot that makes offers based on the current price of XLM. A simpler way would be sell your asset for another asset anchored to USD that you trust. If you want, you could even have a zero spread by using passive sell orders and buy orders with the same price.

However, as I said, there's no way to set a fixed price. If you make an offer to sell 1000 of your asset at a price of $50 each, then when people have bought 1000 of your asset, you'll have to make a new sell order.

Comment: Thank you so much. got it
So how can I share my selling and buying in stellarx.com?

Comment: I think you need to associate a domain with the asset and host a proper stellar.toml file. You can read about that here:
https://developers.stellar.org/docs/issuing-assets/publishing-asset-info/
I also think StellarX only shows assets with low spreads. So if you only have sell orders, it won't show up.